# Load dataframe using spark error: Cannot cast ARRAY into a StructType

Tags: mongodb, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

When I load data from MongoDB into a data frame using spark, there is one field with `ObjecType` and `ArrayType` whose value is null due to missing data, when I `df.show()` I get an error:

> Cannot cast ARRAY into a StructType at documents that are arrays.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post the full error and the location in the code where the error occurs?

Comment: yes, I just posted the full error in the answer and the code. Please help me find this problem